# How to aggregate array values in JSONB?

Tags: json, postgresql, aggregation, jsonb

I have the following PostgreSQL table:

```
CREATE TABLE orders
(
    id uuid NOT NULL,
    order_date timestamp without time zone,
    data jsonb
);
```

Where data contains json documents like this:

```
{
    "screws": [
        {
            "qty": 1000,
            "value": "Wood screw"
        },
        {
            "qty": 500,
            "value": "Drywall screw"
        },
        {
            "qty": 500,
            "value": Concrete screw"
        }
    ],
    "nails": [
        {
            "qty": 1000,
            "value": "Round Nails"
        }
    ]
}
```

How do I can get an overall quantity for all types of screws across all orders? Something like this :)

```
select value, sum(qty) from orders where section = 'screws' group by value;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not quite sure why you are trying to sum up the `qty` values, because the `GROUP BY value` makes only sense if there would be several times the same `value` which can be summed, e.g. if you would have twice the value `Wood screw`.

Nevertheless, this would be the query:

[step-by-step demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=94100fa51cbf1a763fdeb0ed154a2fff)

```
SELECT
    elems ->> 'value' AS value,
    SUM((elems ->> 'qty')::int) AS qty
FROM
    orders,
    jsonb_array_elements(data -> 'screws') elems
GROUP BY 1
```

1. Expand the screw array into one row per array element by `jsonb_array_elements()`
2. Get the qty value by the `->>` operator (which gives out a `text` type) and cast this into type `int`
3. If really necessary, aggregate these key/value pairs.